# Office add-in ribbon button

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-addins

I'm trying out the new style JavaScript based office add-ins and can't see how I can add the add-in launcher button to the ribbon.
I know that Command add-ins which can add tabs etc are not released yet, I'm just talking about a button that will launch my add-in.

It's a TaskPaneApp.

It seems to be possible because (in my version of office 16 at least) I can see that under the Insert tab, Wikipedia add-in has it own button in the Add-In group.

Currently I've just added a Shared Drive as a trusted location and am launching the app from there.  As this is an internal app, it's likely to stay there.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add some elements to your manifest file:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt621545.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but you've posted a link to add-in command, if you read my question I've already mentioned these. They are AFAIK not fully released yet. Also, you need to 'Insert' the app before the commands appear. You close Office and they are gone. I am looking for a permanent button to launch my app from the ribbon. Unless I am missing something??

Comment: It is only Outlook where Ribbon buttons are not fully supported yet (only in OL 2016). AFAIK a Ribbon button is the only way to manually launch a TaskPane add-in outside of inserting it. Also, Word Online is not supported yet.  See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt607161.aspx

Comment: That article is titled Preview. I need to install the first release build and run a special registry edit. I'm not sure that really counts as fully supported. Yet!  That said, I have tried all that and got it working great. But every time I close down word/excel I need to go to insert add-in again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Word, Excel or PowerPoint; it must be 16 or higher.

Also, make sure to use HTTPS requests.

The XML manifest is super sensitive.

Look for closing `/>` for all the tags, because you might be missing them somewhere.

You could also use [this NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-validator) which is supported by Microsoft to validate your XML file.